# calling a function automatically

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have a form that needs to make some validations to automaticall fill another fields, i want that function to be called automatically after all the required values are filled, i tried to do this with one onChange on the last field but it wouldnt work if the user fill that input before the other ones.

any suggestion? this is my api call

```
    const getRFC = ({vLastName,vSecondLastName,vName,vSecondName,vBirthDate}) => {
  ForceApi.post(`/GetRfcController.php`, {  vName, vSecondName, vLastName, vSecondLastName, vBirthDate })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data.resultRFC);
      setvRFC(res.data.resultRFC);
    })
}
```

this are my text inputs and date picker

```
 return ( 
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
            placeholder="Nombre"
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
            onChangeText={newvName => setvName(newvName.toUpperCase())}
            value={vName}
            autoCorrect={false}
            autoCapitalize='characters'
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
            placeholder="Segundo nombre"
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
            onChangeText={newvSecondName => setvSecondName(newvSecondName.toUpperCase())}
            value={vSecondName}
            autoCorrect={false}
            autoCapitalize='characters'
          />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
              placeholder="Apellido paterno"
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              onChangeText={newvLastName => setvLastName(newvLastName.toUpperCase())}
              value={vLastName}
              autoCorrect={false}
              autoCapitalize='characters'
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
              placeholder="Apellido materno"
              onChangeText={newvSecondLastName => setvSecondLastName(newvSecondLastName.toUpperCase())}
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              value={vSecondLastName}
              autoCorrect={false}
              autoCapitalize='characters'
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.containerdate}>
            <DatePicker 
              date={vBirthDate} //initial date from state
              mode="date" //The enum of date, datetime and time
              placeholder="select date"
              format="DD/MM/YYYY"
              minDate="01/01/1900"
              maxDate="01/01/2019"
              confirmBtnText="Confirm"
              cancelBtnText="Cancel"
              androidMode="spinner"
              customStyles={{
                placeholderText: {
                  fontSize: 16,
                },
                dateIcon: {
                  height: 0,
                  width: 0,
                },
                dateText: {
                  color: '#b3b4b5',
                  fontSize: 16,
                },
                dateInput: {
                  borderWidth: 0,
                }
              }}
              onDateChange={(date) => {setvBirthDate(date);} }
            />
          </View>
```

this is the text input that has to be updated with the value of the api

```
         <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
              placeholder={vRFC}
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              value= {vRFC}
              editable={false} 
              selectTextOnFocus={false}
              autoCorrect={false}
              autoCapitalize='characters'
            />
          </View>
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have a single object for state of every input. which would allow easy access of input value from all component. And on each event you can do input validation and if all is well perform some action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `useEffect` hook

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (vLastName && vSecondLastName && vName && vSecondName && vBirthDate) {
        getRFC({vLastName, vSecondLastName, vName, vSecondName, vBirthDate});
    }
}, [vLastName, vSecondLastName, vName, vSecondName, vBirthDate]);
```

Comment: srry i tried this but it throws me error it says that vLastName its undefined

Comment: Could you update your question above with your full latest code?

Comment: the problem was that in getRFC(); i wasnt sending the parameters

Comment: If your `getRFC` need params, you have to pass them to your method call. See updated answer above.